# Boot SSD Already At 86% Health?

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, nvme, trim

In late November I started using a new SSD, the Sabrent Rocket 4 Plus 2TB, as my boot drive.  The drive is rated for 1400 TBW but is already saying it's at 86% health despite only having 12TB written to the drive.  Windows Defrag and Optimize was set to run weekly so I'm not sure if the bug listed [Here](https://www.tomsguide.com/news/windows-10-update-could-kill-your-ssd-what-you-need-to-know) is causing the health to go down or if it is some other issue?  My non-boot drive SSD for storing games is still at 96% health despite having more data written to it.

CrystalDiskMark Info for Main Drive:

[image]

CrystalDiskMark Info for Storage SSD:

[image]

Comment: You may as well like to try if any vendor provided SSD Monitoring tools are available and use the same to check SSD health. e.g. https://www.sabrent.com/rocket-control-panel/

Comment: Thank you!  I was trying to find something on their site to monitor it but couldn't locate it on their site!  It definitely says 100% health on their tool.